# I am getting 500 error when I use trailing slash

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am getting 500 error when I put trailing slash with any of the url but homepage. I tried to follow one of the posts from Stack Overflow community but unable to understand how I can follow for my .htaccess file.

For reference, I am leaving it here. What mistake I am making here?

```
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^imperialimmigration.ca
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.imperialimmigration.ca/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^index$ "https\:\/\/www\.imperialimmigration\.ca\/" [R=301,L]

# browser requests PHP
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ $1 [L,R=301]

# check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ $1.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^lmia$ "https\:\/\/www\.imperialimmigration\.ca\/apply\-lmia/" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^work\-visa$ "https\:\/\/www\.imperialimmigration\.ca\/work\-visa\-for\-canada\.php" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^imperialimmigration\.ca$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.imperialimmigration\.ca$
RewriteRule ^ecsaw\/lmia$ "https\:\/\/www\.imperialimmigration\.ca\/apply\-lmia" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^imperialimmigration\.ca$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.imperialimmigration\.ca$
RewriteRule ^apply\-for\-lmia$ "https\:\/\/www\.imperialimmigration\.ca\/apply\-lmia" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^imperialimmigration\.ca$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.imperialimmigration\.ca$
RewriteRule ^provincial\-nominees$ "https\:\/\/www\.imperialimmigration\.ca\/pnp\-for\-canada" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^form$ "https\:\/\/imperialimmigration\.ca\/express\-entry\-crs\-point\-calculator" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^PersonalInformationForm\.pdf$ "https\:\/\/imperialimmigration\.ca\/personalInformationform\.pdf" [R=301,L]

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php74” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74___lsphp .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^\#\!$ "https\:\/\/www\.imperialimmigration\.ca\/" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^index$ "https\:\/\/www\.imperialimmigration\.ca\/" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^index\#\!$ "https\:\/\/imperialimmigration\.ca\/" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^imperialimmigration\.ca$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.imperialimmigration\.ca$
```

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: What is your preferred canonical URL... with or without a trailing slash?

Comment: This is the url without trailing slash
https://www.imperialimmigration.ca/pnp-for-canada


When you put the slash end of the URL it'll show a 500 error.

Comment: So, the preferred canonical URL is the URL _without_ a trailing slash?

Comment: `RewriteOptions inherit` - And what directives are you _inheriting_?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> # check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
> RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ $1.php [L]
> ```

Your 500 error is most probably caused by this rule. The *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) is not necessarily checking the same URL you are ultimately rewriting to. If you append a trailing slash, eg. `/foo/` and `/foo.php` exists then the *condition* will be successful, but it will rewrite the request to `/foo/.php` (which does not exist) - this ultimately results in a rewrite-loop and a "500 Internal Server Error" response is sent.

You need to check the same URL-path you are rewriting to. For example:

```
# check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

However, this does not completely resolve your issue, since a URL with a trailing slash (that should ultimately map to a `.php` file) will now result in a 404. (Although this may be desirable.)

You need to decide on the preferred canonical URL: with or without a trailing slash? (ie. Which URL version are you linking to internally?) And "redirect" from one to the other. Assuming the canonical URL should **not** have a trailing slash then add the following rule near the top of the `.htaccess` file, immediately below the `RewriteEngine` directive:

```
# Remove trailing slash from non-directory requests
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-d
RewriteRule (.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

(Test first with a 302 temporary redirect to avoid caching issues.)

You need to be linking consistently internally (either with or without the trailing slash) - you should not have a mix of both.

---

#### Preferred canonical includes the trailing slash

If, however, the preferred canonical URL includes a trailing slash then you would need to modify both the above rules as follows:

```
# Append trailing slash to non-file requests
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$0 !-f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ /$0/ [R=301,L]

# check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1.php [L]
```

Where `$0` is a backreference that contains the entire match from the `RewriteRule` *pattern* and `$1` contains the value of the parenthesised subpattern.